# Non linear programming problem using Kuhn-Tucker method

Tags: optimization

Solve using Kuhn-Tucker method
$ z=x_1^2+x_2^2 $subject to 
i) $ x_1+x_2\le 4$
ii)$ 2x_1+x_2\le 5$
where $ x_1\ge 0 ,x_2\ge 0$